# How to add multiple worksheet in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

How to add multiple worksheets using phpexcel class.

```
$this->excel = new PHPExcel();
```

Comment: Start by RTFMing? https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/06-Worksheets.md

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/06-Worksheets.md)

```
// Create a new worksheet called "My Data"
$myWorkSheet = new PHPExcel_Worksheet($objPHPExcel, 'My Data');

// Attach the "My Data" worksheet as the first worksheet in the PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel->addSheet($myWorkSheet, 0);
```

Comment: In addition to using `addSheet()` there's also `$objPHPExcel->createSheet()`, though you'll need to set the worksheet title after calling createSheet()